# WebAPI Consumption Statistics

Tags: c#, webapi

I was wondering if the Visual Studio WebAPI project has built-in functions already for tracking the consumption of your Endpoint routes that you configure?

For example; if i create the following route which returns a list of all users within a DB.

```
http://api/users
```

After a week, if i want to see how many times that API Endpoint was used, can I?

Comment: There is nothing built in available from visual studio or asp.net core.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya, appreciate the comment. I was hoping there was a way I could tell if my endpoints were being used or not, or if it was better to just remove them from the catalogue due to low or no usage.

Comment: Find a logging solution (NLog, whatever). Log everything in your controller. Get a log analyzer, analyze the logs. You _may_ be able to get what you want from an analysis of your web-server logs. Look at Splunk or Kibana for ideas